# Convert List to Int with logical ORs

Tags: c#, asp.net

In C#, I have a function that takes as an argument an int like this:

```
searchValue = (int)(svcMembership.Request.Active | svcMembership.Request.Inactive);

userClient.DelegateAccounts_Retrieve(searchValue);
```

I have a CheckBoxList that supplies choices for this list and I've captured selected items from that as a `List<svcMembership.Request>` (`svcMembership.Request` is an Enum).

Is there a way to convert that List into an integer with the logical ORs as shown in the first example?

Comment: They're not logical ORs. They're bitwise operators. There's a pretty large difference!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Assuming you have a list of `svcMembership.Request` and want the int value of the 1st | 2nd | 3rd | 4th, I guess you could use linq: `list.Aggregate((a,b)=> a | b)`. Oh, someone beat me to it. nvm.

Comment: Bitwise operators ... thank you ... I'm new to this syntax. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;

int searchValue = mySelectedEnumValues.Cast<int>().Aggregate(0, (a, b) => a | b);
```

Make sure that `svcMembership.Request` has values in powers of two.

Also, look at the [Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.flagsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute.

Comment: That looks good, but VS is telling me: "Operator '|' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and svcMembership.Request"

Comment: Here is the enum: 
    `public enum Request
    {
        Requested = 0x01,
        Active = 0x02,
        Inactive = 0x04,
        Rejected = 0x08
    }`

Comment: @DelfordChaffin Instead of using `0` as the seed, use `default(svcMembership.Request)`.  You'll need to cast the result to an int if you want to end up with an int.

Comment: Final code (thanks @allonhadaya and @Servy):  

`int searchValue = Convert.ToInt32(RequestModes.Aggregate(default(svcMembership.Request), (a, b) => a | b));`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistakes @Servy and DelfordChaffin. Take a look at the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered iterating the `checkbox_list.Items`, adding `Selected` and multiplying by two each iteration?

```
int checkbox_list_bits = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < checkbox_list.Items.Count; x++) {
    checkbox_list_bits *= 2;
    if (checkbox_list.Items[x].Selected) { checkbox_list_bits++; }
}
```